# MSAL Library Config for Anguar 7 to work with tenant.b2clogin.com

Tags: angular, angular7, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

Current version of @azure/msal-angular library used in our Angular 7 application is 0.1.4

Configuration in app.module.ts for MSAL is:

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
      clientID: environment.clientID,
      authority: environment.authority,
      redirectUri: environment.redirectUri,
      validateAuthority: true,
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: environment.postLogoutRedirectUri,
      protectedResourceMap: protectedResourceMap,
      unprotectedResources: ['./assets/i18n/en.json'],
      consentScopes: [environment.clientScope1],
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
      logger: loggerCallback,
      popUp: false,
      isAngular: true,
    }),
```

In the above config, if `validateAuthority` is set `true` application doesn't bring up the login screen. 
Rather it gives AADSTS50049 exception in browser developer window.
For now, I have set the `validateAuthority` to `false` and application lets me log in.

How should the MSAL be configured to support the latest `tenant.b2clogin.com` sothat the application works with Angular 7?

Comment: Experienced the same issue. Temporary i will be sticking to the recent field-tested way of setting the authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/policy'
That way validateAuthority can stay true until they sort that out.